# Getting Multiple Inputs and checking if they are Perfect squares or not without using math

Tags: python, loops, user-input, perfect-square

```
def isPerfectSquare(n) :
 
    i = 1
    while(i * i<= n):
        if ((n % i == 0) and (n / i == i)):
            return True
        i = i + 1
    return False

lst=[]
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
  ele=int(input("Enter: "))
  lst.append(ele)
for i in lst:
  isPerfectSquare(i)
  if (isPerfectSquare(n)):
    print("Perf")
  else:
    print("Not")
```

I am a new python programmer so I am trying out different low levelled problems with a twist. I tried with for loops first but couldn't figure out how to do it with multiple inputs.
Where did I go wrong? When I input a perfect square, it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is `if (isPerfectSquare(n)):` you were always just passing in the input and checking if that is a Perfect Square. You should be passing in each element of the list instead like this `if isPerfectSquare(i):`

```
def isPerfectSquare(n):
    i = 1
    while i * i <= n:
        if (n % i == 0) and (n / i == i):
            return True
        i = i + 1
    return False


lst = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(0, n):
    ele = int(input("Enter: "))
    lst.append(ele)
for i in lst:
    if isPerfectSquare(i):
        print("Perf")
    else:
        print("Not")
```

**Output:**

```
3
Enter: 1
Enter: 4
Enter: 10
Perf
Perf
Not
```